# how install github repo on C++ project with Conan

Tags: c++, conan

In context of first app C++ project, I would like to work with existing C++ library which bring me a concrete challenge for working.

Conan seems to be the more full-features-widely-used package manager for C++.

And I would like to get this package : https://github.com/jcelerier/libremidi

1/ I installed conan with :  `pip install conan` (conan --version = 2.0.17)

2/ created my conan profile like this : `conan profile detect`

```
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.version=193
os=Windows
```

3/ I created conanfile.txt file in parent of project directory :

```
[requires]
libremidi/4.2.4@https://github.com/jcelerier/libremidi.git

[generators]
cmake
```

4/ Added new remote repo in conan like this : `conan remote add libre_midi_repo https://github.com/jcelerier/libremidi.git`

5/ I try to install the repo like this :

- `conan install .. --remote=libre_midi_repo` or
- `conan install ..`

Those 2 commands return me this error :

> ERROR: Package
> 'libremidi/4.2.4@https://github.com/jcelerier/libremidi.git' not
> resolved: Unable to find
> 'libremidi/4.2.4@https://github.com/jcelerier/libremidi.git' in
> remotes.

---

It seems that conan has a particular concepts that more complex to understand than (Composer for PHP or Npm for Node for exemple).

Can you tell me to understand their subtlilities of Conan to get and work with external package that not in the official conan repo ?

Comment: I believe in order to use any library it must have a Conan recipe which describes how to build the library and how to consume it. By saying that I mean IMHO it is not possible to use any arbitrary library from Git repo via Conan. Try with the Git submodules first.

Comment: It seems you are using a Conan 1.X legacy ``cmake`` generator, that was removed in Conan 2.0. You should be using ``CMakeDeps`` and ``CMakeToolchain``, please make sure that you are not reading Conan 1.X docs when using Conan 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conan for C and C++ is more similar to Maven for Java package manager than to other languages package managers like npm or pip, and for downloading packages it requires having a server for the packages. In the same way PyPI for pip and MavenCentral for Java, there is also [ConanCenter](https://conan.io/center) for Conan packages, and the way to contribute recipes for open-source packages is to do PRs to the [conan-center-index Github repo](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index)

There is some ongoing work in this PR that tries to allow to use folders with recipes, but still a draft and uncertain to be merged, and in any case discovery would be challenging, if the goal is to make it easy to use by the larger community, then contributing to ConanCenter would be the way.

If the goal is to use that package internally for a team, there are several options, the recommended one is the free ArtifactoryCE that can be downloaded from the [Conan downloads page](https://conan.io/downloads).

Comment: For docs about setting up remotes, have a look at https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/conan_repositories.html

Comment: I understand your response (and validate and thank you). However, I think I will find a different way to proceed with my POC project. Perhaps I will revisit the Conan solution later, but it seems like overkill for a local test concept at this time.

Comment: I run the free server downloaded from https://conan.io/downloads, even in Windows just downloading and double clicking the artifactory.bat file and it works well and takes me like just 3-4 of minutes to download and run. If the long term plan is to create your own packages for private usage in your organization, this is an industry best practice and standard, not only for Conan. If that is your use case, then the initial proof of concept should probably also include package server side, and trying to avoid it might lead you to future suboptimal solutions.